# async await in condition

Tags: c#, asynchronous

How can I do this with async/await so both conditions are evaluated together?
Here is the code I'm currently working on. I tried using Result with the condition and receive a deadlock.

```
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customer))
            {
                var resp = await  _securityService.GetCustomerShiptoAuthorizationAsync(User.Identity.Name, customer, ship);

                response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Invalid Username, Password, Customer or Ship.");
            }
```

This is the previous code that is non async/await and conditions are evaluated together.

```
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customer) && !_securityService.GetCustomerShiptoAuthorization(
                User.Identity.Name,
                customer,
                ship).IsAuthorized)
            {

                response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Invalid Username, Password, Customer or Ship.");
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put parentheses around the `await` call.

```
else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customer) && !(await _securityService.GetCustomerShiptoAuthorizationAsync(User.Identity.Name, customer, ship).IsAuthorized))
{
    response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Invalid Username, Password, Customer or Ship.");
}
```

Comment: that did it. Thank you!